# Generating Google refresh token with API

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, refresh-token

I wrote some python scripts collecting data from Google. I am using refresh tokens to authenticate but they expire after some time so I have to go through Google Oauth Playground to generate new refresh token.

Is there a way to automate this via API? I've tried following a video on YT: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0RKgHskYwI  but due to some security limitations in my company, I am unable to finish the process as my localhost is refusing the connection.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I managed to complete the tutorial from YT video, however it requires user to copy-paste URLs which is not ideal in terms of automation in the script. Ideally it would happen in the 'back-end' after providing all neccessary info like client ID, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: What api are you using?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I'm using Business Profile, https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews

Comment: strange they haven't created a python sample.

Comment: Someone said it;s not possible due to some security restrictions on Google's side but I'm not sure how accurate it is. I thought there will be some python libraries/modules to make it possible.

Comment: Well it apers to be part of google apis which means the google apis python client library should work with it.   Meaning you could grab the auth code from any one of the samples from say drive or calendar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding your client ID and secret in the playground and your app is still in the testing phase then the refresh token will expire after seven days. The solution would be to set your app into production. on the developer console.

If you did not supply your client ID and the client secret in the playground then I think the refresh token only lasts about three hours.

Ideally, you should be handling the token request and refresh within your application and not relying on the playground that is intended just for development and testing.

Comment: It expires after about a month or more, not sure exactly